# What is the :counter_sql option for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What is the `:counter_sql` option for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here: [rubyonrails association_basics](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html). Find for `:counter_sql` in this page.

---

By `:counter_sql` you can specify your own counting sql like `:couter_sql=>"select * from table where user=#{user}"`. If you so not specify it Rails automatically generates the proper SQL  for counting.

Comment: I actually don't understand the description there. I'm not too familiar with SQL. So you're counting the number of elements returned from the query? Why would you do that?

Comment: maybe this is more of an SQL question but what exactly is counting in this sense? why is `:finder_sql` not enough?

Comment: went designing a database, you can store and update the counter as a number for performance reasons. by specifying a different query, this allows you to get the value from your denormalized total, rather than having to do a query that enumerates all the items in the association.

Comment: @garethm ahh ok, and for what practical reasons would you need to use the counter?

Comment: An example of a counter like this is StackOverflow - on the main page it shows the count of answers for each question listed.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `count(*)`? The page no longer documents this option.

Answer (score 0):

And I quote

> Specify a complete SQL statement to fetch the size of the association.
>   If :finder_sql is specified but not :counter_sql, :counter_sql will be
>   generated by replacing `SELECT ... FROM with SELECT COUNT(*) FROM.`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html